# jQuery fancybox destroying object on close

Tags: jquery, animation, fancybox

I have a set of DIVs I intend to display inside a fancybox on click. The fancybox successfully fetches the element and its contents; however, when I click the cancel button to close the fancybox or click outside the fancybox so it can disappear, it disappears and abducts the element along with it i.e. removes the element from the DOM entirely. I have tried applying the keys from [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) but none of them is active or effects the changes therein.

I'm thinking of maybe storing a copy of that element in a variable when the fancybox plugin is called (`using beforeLoad`) and doing a `insertBefore` in the `afterClose` key but nothing works (including the `leftRatio` properties).

I've tried working with quoted and unquoted keys. I use v2.1.5 and also added v1.3.4 for the easing but it doesn't work even if when I omit the possibly extraneous version. My code looks something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".new-post a[href*='#fancy']").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'speedIn': 1400,
        'speedOut': 300,
        'overlayShow': false,
        'autoCenter': true,
        'padding': [0, 0, 0, 20%],
        'margin': [0, 0, 0, 20%],
        'leftRatio': 1
    });
});

$(".more").click(function() {
    $("#fancy_outer").css({ "float": "right", "position": "static" }); /* I tried this also -_- */
    var that = $(this),
        id = $(that).parent().attr("id");
    console.log($(that)[0].nodeName);
    //use var that inside another object
});
```

**EDIT**

My new script using colorbox

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".new-post a[href*='#colorbox']").colorbox();
  });
```

*Markup*
            
                      
                       
                         Then Go Even Deeper And Narrower

```
            A young Eritrean man in his early twenties has two nephews and      one niece but is particularly fond of the niece; partly because they both share              similar traits
                                and temperaments. During each visit to her parents' home, they spend the most time together, with her clinging unto him. Her pud...</p>
               </div>
               <a href="#colorbox22" class="cboxElement">
               <div class="more"> More »</div> </a>
               <div class="push"> <a href="#"> push </a></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you provide HTML code of fancybox. It might be possible that you are calling wrong class.

Comment: @NimishJain I have just ditched using it in favour of colorbox. The problem now is, the interface is using a tabbed interface I wrote using css flexbox. When the animation finishes, a new dom object is thrown into the tabbed structure and everything goes awry. I might just probably forget about the whole setup

Comment: @NimishJain I just noticed it loads the entire document into the popup. How do I stop this? Idk if you use TeamViewer or something?

Comment: @NimishJain I've added markup and my new colorbox code

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem that when I click on image, it successfully opened in fancybox,but on closing fancybox image object was destroying. and it loads again on refreshing page in rails.
My html was like:

```
<div class="item1"
  <a id="single_1" href="ca34ef74d9_b.jpg">
    <img src="ca34ef74d9_m.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
```

My script was `$(".item1").fancybox();`
I was calling div class.
instead that I have to call anchor tag Id.
I replaced script with :

> $("#single_1").fancybox();